# How to browse wap sites from Windows PC?

Tags: website

Usually PC browsers don't support wap sites.Is there any way to browse wap site which are made for mobile from PC?

Comment: Which browsers did you try?

Answer (score 1):

you can use opera web browser it support wap site also [Download opera from here](http://www.opera.com/computer/windows)

or in mozilla install  [wnlbrowser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wmlbrowser/)

Answer (score 0):

You can find various WAP emulators around if you try on your favourite search engine. If you use Firefox there is even a very nice plugin for it to browse WAP sites called [wmlbrowser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wmlbrowser/) that I used ages ago (now WAP is kinda a bit out of fashion)